# ntheorem + autoref + aliascnt cause TeX to exceed grouplimit capacity

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, ntheorem

I'm using MikTeX 2.9. When processing the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{aliascnt}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newaliascnt{definition}{lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}[definition]{Definition}
\aliascntresetthe{definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
\label{def:first}
This is my definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}[Alternative to \autoref{def:first}]
This is my second definition.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

I get:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
\HyRef@autoref #1#2->\begingroup 
                                 \Hy@safe@activestrue \expandafter \HyRef@au...
l.31 ...ition}[Alternative to \autoref{def:first}]
```

If I remove the autoref, all is well. This doesn't happen to me with `amsthm` instead of `ntheorem`. Am I doing something wrong? Is it an `ntheorem` bug? an `aliascnt` bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at least I can have nice macro for this:

```
\makeatletter
\def\newaliasedtheorem#1[#2]#3{%
  \newaliascnt{#1@alt}{#2}
  \newtheorem{#1}[#1@alt]{#3}
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1@altname\endcsname{#3}
}
\makeatother
```

Use it instead of  `\newtheorem`, i.e. rather than:

```
\newtheorem{mynewenv}[existingcounter]{MyNewEnvName}
```

do

```
\newaliasedtheorem{mynewenv}[existingcounter]{MyNewEnvName}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work; the problem seems to be in the counter's name

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\definautorefname{Definition}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newaliascnt{defin}{lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}[defin]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
\label{def:first}
This is my definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}[Alternative to \autoref{def:first}]
This is my second definition.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: also, `hyperref` should be loaded last (as you've done).

Comment: But why shouldn't it just work the way it is, without me having to use a different counter name? :-(

Comment: Sorry, ask Heiko Oberdiek; he is always very keen on receiving comments and bug reports.

Comment: @egreg: Just though I'd report I wrote Heiko Oberdiek (heiko.oberdiek at googlemail dot com) on 2011-07-23, and he hasn't answered yet.